# How to correct convert bytes to bytes32 and then convert back?

Tags: solidity

I have two contract, main contract require input in bytes 32 array, then main convert bytes 32 to address, uint 256 , and bytes and call second contract, which require input in address, uint 256, and bytes

I am trying convert this bytes data in bytes 32

"0x793e39cd00000000000000000000000064a436ae831c1672ae81f674cab8b6775df3475c0000000000000000000000004a6bc4e803c62081ffebcc8d227b5a87a58f1f8f000000000000000000000000c4375b7de8af5a38a93548eb8453a498222c4ff20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b9de674df070000"

But when I convert this data from bytes32 back to bytes I got this

"0x793e39cd00000000000000000000000064a436ae831c1672ae81f674cab8b677"

For convert bytes32 to bytes I use

```
abi.encodePacked()
```

For convert bytes to bytes 32 I found this code, but this not correct.

```
function bytesToBytes32(bytes memory source) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    if (source.length == 0) {
        return 0x0;
    }
    assembly {
        result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to convert your `bytes` to a `bytes32[]`, maybe you can try something like:

```
function bytesToBytes32Array(bytes memory data)
    public
    pure
    returns (bytes32[] memory)
{
    // Find 32 bytes segments nb
    uint256 dataNb = data.length / 32;
    // Create an array of dataNb elements
    bytes32[] memory dataList = new bytes32[](dataNb);
    // Start array index at 0
    uint256 index = 0;
    // Loop all 32 bytes segments
    for (uint256 i = 32; i <= data.length; i = i + 32) {
        bytes32 temp;
        // Get 32 bytes from data
        assembly {
            temp := mload(add(data, i))
        }
        // Add extracted 32 bytes to list
        dataList[index] = temp;
        index++;
    }
    // Return data list
    return (dataList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The data `0x793e39cd00000000000000000000000064a436ae831c1672ae81f674cab8b6775df3475c0000000000000000000000004a6bc4e803c62081ffebcc8d227b5a87a58f1f8f000000000000000000000000c4375b7de8af5a38a93548eb8453a498222c4ff20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b9de674df070000`

is 132 bytes long, and `bytes32` can only hold 32 bytes of data. The code you found is working correctly, but it discards all the data after the first 32 bytes because it's impossible to fit that in a `bytes32`.

If you're looking for converting into an array (`bytes32[]`), then Phoax's code may be helpful; if you really need it to be `bytes32` you might want to look at the data closely, as it looks like it's a couple of different pieces of data packed together and padded mostly to 32 or 64 bytes. From the context, you might only need one of them to be passed as a `bytes32`.